# return an observable after more subscribe in Angular6

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular6, subscribe

Hi i have a global service for several applications and i wish to make a method with several subscribes in order to stock and initialize all my datas and i wish make a subscribe to this method in my appComponent but i don't know how to make that

In my service

```
private initData(isLogged: boolean) {
   this.http.get('/api/conf').subscribe(
      conf => {
        this.http.get('api/param').subscribe(
          tokResp => {
            this.appParams.token = tkResp.queoval;
            this.appParams.culture = tkResp.culture;
            this.appParams.GMT = tkResp.gmt;
            this.http.get('/api/trad').subscribe(
              trad => {
                this.label = trad
                // return an Observable
               }
             )
           }
         )
      }
   )
}
```

In my AppComponent

```
this.service.initData().subscribe(
result => {
   this.test = result
}
```

How can i make that? I can't find the information in the documentation. Thank you for your help. It's important for my work, i used so much time to research for nothing :(

Answer (score 1):

So since you want to make multiple async requests one after the other, you should use the observable function [".flatMap"](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) (this is very similar to a Promises ".then"). The ".flatMap" function allows you to wait until the first request is completed before you continue.

So in your case, you would want your service to look something like this:

```
private initData(isLogged: boolean) {
   return this.http.get('/api/conf').flatMap(
      conf => {
        return this.http.get('api/param');
      }
   ).flatMap(
      tokResp => {
        this.appParams.token = tkResp.queoval;
        this.appParams.culture = tkResp.culture;
        this.appParams.GMT = tkResp.gmt;
        return this.http.get('/api/trad');
      }
    ).flatMap(
       trad => {
         this.label = trad;
         return trad;
       }
    );
}
```

This function has all of the async requests chained together through ".flatMap" so that they are only called after the previous request completes.

The component file looks fine and should work with this new service.

> As a general note, you should never subscribe to the observable inside
>   of the service. You should instead use functions like map, flatMap,
>   forkJoin ...

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, i have look for documentation and i found my response:    initApp() :Observable<any>{

    return this.http.get('./assets/tata.json').pipe(
            mergeMap((tata: any) => {
              console.log(tata.key)
              return this.http.get('./assets/tutu.json').pipe(
                mergeMap((tutu: any) => {
                console.log(tutu.key)
                return this.http.get('./assets/titi.json')
                
          })
        )}
      ))
    }
  }